# How to identify a ConcurrentQueue<Func<CancellationToken, Task>> item?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

from this sample: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)
Using the following queue.

```
public class BackgroundTaskQueue : IBackgroundTaskQueue
{
    public ConcurrentQueue<Func<CancellationToken, Task>> _workItems =
        new ConcurrentQueue<Func<CancellationToken, Task>>();
    private SemaphoreSlim _signal = new SemaphoreSlim(0);

    public void QueueBackgroundWorkItem(
        Func<CancellationToken, Task> workItem)
    {
        if (workItem == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(workItem));
        }

        _workItems.Enqueue(workItem);
        _signal.Release();
    }

    public async Task<Func<CancellationToken, Task>> DequeueAsync(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _signal.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
        _workItems.TryDequeue(out var workItem);

        return workItem;
    }
}
```

Calling it from within an api controller but need to be able to check on its status.

Controller:

```
var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();           
queue.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async token=>{
   await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), token);
});
```

How do I associate the guid to the task and check on it later?

Comment: use it in a concurrent dictionary.

Comment: @DanielA.White - don't follow.  Are you saying replace ConcurrentQueue with ConcurrentDictionary in the code above and not use a queue at all?

Comment: no use both types

Comment: @DanielA.White - okay, but why is there a need for both?  Enqueue to a queue is analogous to adding to a dictionary, isn't it?

Comment: no. The queue is fifo. The dictionary provides look ups